# if statement run when condition fail bind with window scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

INFO

I am trying to build a one page website where, when user scroll a bit, it automatically snap to the next section,  my logic here is to

1. get all scroll top of section,
2. find the nearest section,
3. depending on the direction of scroll

please see complete code here 
http://jsfiddle.net/e3fed8sw/
I commented out the `goTo()` function b/c it break the site.  please uncomment it before you try.

QUESTION:

why goTo() still run when it fail the direction test?

I think this might be where the problem is.

```
function checkScrollDirection(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 0;
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return false;

if (st > lastScrollTop){
// downscroll code
    return "down";
} else {
// upscroll code
    return "up";
}
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

DOM READY

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        var onePageLoacations = []; 

        $('.onePage').each(
            function(index, el) {
                onePage($(el));
                var onePageLoacation = getOnePageLocation($(el));
                    onePageLoacations.push(onePageLoacation);
            }
        );

        $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {

            var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
                direction = checkScrollDirection();
                onePageCount = onePageLoacations.length, 
                topPosArray = [];
                i = 0;                      

                console.log('is traveling '+direction);

            for(i; i<onePageCount; i++) {
                topPosArray.push(onePageLoacations[i][0]);
            }

            var closestCord = closest(topPosArray,currentPos), 
                pageNumber = topPosArray.indexOf(closestCord),  // 0 base
                currentPage = $('.onePage').eq(pageNumber),
                nextPage = currentPage.next('.onePage');

                if(direction==="down") {
                    var currentThreshold = closestCord + 50;
                    if(currentPos > currentThreshold) {
                        goTo(currentPage, nextPage);
                        console.log('goto active');
                    } else {
                        console.log('condition not met');
                    }
                } else {

                }
        });

    }
);
```

Comment: Why don't you just check which .onePage index is currently displayed (or hold a var), then animate either 1 index up or down according to the scroll direction?

Comment: @Zze wow, that would actually be better, thanks

Comment: I would create an example for you, but I don't have the time right now sorry, but yeah, I think it would be more efficient :) - good luck! See: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: @Zze I posted an answer, can you take a look? sometime I just need a sentence to point to the right direction. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems with your `checkScrollDirection` function:

1. It reinitialize your `lastScrollTop` everytime, so it doesn't remember the last value
2. You never assign the current `st` value to `lastScrollTop` because the assignement is done after the `return` statement.

To fix it:

- Make your `lastScrollTop` variable global (declare it outside the function body)
- Don't assign a new value to it every call of the function
- Assign the current `st` value to it correctly

Code:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
function checkScrollDirection(){
    var delta = 0;
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return false;

    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        lastScrollTop = st;
        return "down";
    } else {
        lastScrollTop = st;
        return "up";
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks, that make sense, I still don't know how should I tackle this... I will try zzz's method now.